# ckeditor5 not saving images in civicrm / Drupal9

Tags: permissions, drupal-9, images, ckeditor5

This is a fresh install of a site which I've migrated data to from an outdated Drupal7/civi site we've used for years. I've installed Drupal-9 using Composer and civicrm (5.64) as well and am using php8.1 on a Ubuntu 22 Linode server. I installed ckeditor5 v1.5 downloaded from CiviCRM into ext folder and enabled through admin > settings > extensions. I then selected 'ckeditor5 with uploaded images (recommended)' from the display preferences. When I try to edit a mailing template by adding an image from the PC I'm working from, the image shows up in the editor but when I save, I get a saved alert but the image disappears. Any text or html changes persist. The image does not appear where I have set them. The upload directory is set to [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/images/. I am working as the admin user. The image folder is owned by www-data:www-data with 775. I tried copying a .png file to the folder and pointing a browser to https://subdomain.siteimworkingon.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/gbc.png it displays the image. If I use developer tools and watch Network tab while I am saving the template there is no obvious post errors or anything I can see. I've also tried summernote editor with similar results. I believe it must be a path or permission issue but I've reached the end of my troubleshooting skills. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Anyone have an idea?